Customize a default diverging matplotlib colormap so that 0 always matches the neutral color
I would like to customize a default matplotlib colormap in such a way that the "neutral" color (the transition color between the "positive" and "negative" color) always matches 0.
Example (note that choosing a matrix as input and plotting that using plt.imshow() is just an example. I am only interested in the cmap object and the resulting colorscale on the right. You could also think about other ways to visualize the data):
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a matrix with lots of positive values and a few negative values
np.random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
shape = (20,20)  # Shape of the matrix
a = 1  # Shape parameter (alpha)
scale = 2.0  # Scale parameter (beta)
matrix = np.random.gamma(a, scale, size=shape) # Create random numbers
matrix = matrix - 1 # We also want negative numbers
matrix  = matrix * -1  # flip values so that lots of numbers are positive and few are negative
matrix[0,0:3] = 0 # some values should be set to exactly 0
matrix[1,0:3] = np.nan # some values should be np.nan
matrix = np.random.permutation(matrix.flatten()).reshape(matrix.shape)
cmap = 'RdBu_r'  # Choose colorscale

# plot matrix and colorscale
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.imshow(matrix, cmap="RdBu_r")
plt.colorbar(label='Matrix')

which produces:

As you can see, 0 does not match white here, which is what I want.

This is the motivation behind a two-slope norm: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormapnorms.html#sphx-glr-users-explain-colors-colormapnorms-py
